# Storing and retrieving data for custom Shopify apps

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

So I am trying to build something for my store but a few things are somewhat unclear.

1. If I need to save some user settings do I need my own backend just
   for that app specifically? For simplicity sake, I want build an app
   to save and display a custom message in cart-template.liquid.To
   achieve that, I think my app should make a request to my backend (let
   say, on heroku) and save it in some db that app is using?
2. How do I retrieve that data in cart-template.liquid? I guess I
   build a snippet that calls a public endpoint of my backend that
   returns that saved message using fetch() or maybe axios.get and
   embed it using {% render 'fetch-custom-message-snippet' %} ?
3. Say I ask for user input, ie. "Engraved message" and the form is in cart-template.liquid,
   of course. The following snippet is used:

   ```
   <p class="line-item-property__field">
     <label for="engraved-message">Engraved message</label>
     <input id="engraved-message" type="text" name="properties[Engraved message]">
   </p>
   ```

   How do I make sure that bit of information is captured and passed to me? I guess I want to see it somewhere in the order details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I need to save some user settings do I need my own backend just for that app specifically? For simplicity sake, I want build an app to save and display a custom message in cart-template.liquid.To achieve that, I think my app should make a request to my backend (let say, on heroku) and save it in some db that app is using?

Yes, you need your own backend. Your application alone is responsible for storing its own information (there are some exceptions like a special order field which I show you below) - that typically infers a database that back ups your service and holds your data. Please check out [this thread](https://dev.to/memahesh/how-to-store-user-data-in-shopify-app-2m86) as you can find lots of valuable information there.

Regarding `cart-template.liquid` I'd suggest taking a look at the official ["Shopify Developers"](https://dev.to/memahesh/how-to-store-user-data-in-shopify-app-2m86) documentation. *All information you're allowed to display and request are neatly explained and ordered there.*

> How do I retrieve that data in cart-template.liquid? I guess I build a snippet that calls a public endpoint of my backend that returns that saved message using fetch() or maybe axios.get and embed it using {% render 'fetch-custom-message-snippet' %} ?

Once again there are good guides out there. I suggest taking a look at [this blog post](https://www.christhefreelancer.com/shopify-liquid-guide/) which goes into in-depth on this topic. [Shopify's documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference) about the Liquid template language is also highly advised to be read.

How do you retrieve that data? According to this [specific example](https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/cart-notes) any input will be supplied to your order page in the Shopify admin. For example:

```
<label for="CartNote">Special instructions</label>
<textarea name="note" id="CartNote">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
```

*taken from https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/cart-notes*; shows a `Special instruction` label and textarea for users to submit details about the oder - you will get this data on, as mentioned, the order page in the Shopify admin.

> Say I ask for user input, ie. "Engraved message" and the form is in
> cart-template.liquid, of course. The following snippet is used:
> *[...]* How do I make sure that bit of information is captured and passed to me? I guess I want to see it somewhere in the order details.

*see above*

**//EDIT:**

To prevent any confusion: It seems like you want to develop a custom app just for personal usage and not to publish it in the [Shopify App Store](https://apps.shopify.com/) - in this case you most often than not don't need an external database; e.g. the example you provided with a simple order request which is easily doable through Shopify's examples.

For your specific case this code snippet (I **modified** your original example to fit the case - it's not a full `cart-template.liquid` obviously; in this case the file is called `cart.liquid`):

```
<label for="engraved-message">Engraved message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="engraved-message">{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
```

**//EDIT 2:**

The link - shared by another user in this thread, namely *@Simas Butavičius* - is actually kind of useful if you have problems with the customization process in general, i.e. if you want to revise some basic concepts or want to check how to implement the code snippet from above in the whole structure of your website I'd advise to skim through [this site](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Get-customization-information-for-products/td-p/616503).

Needless to say, there are hundreds of [good tutorials](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Use-cart-attributes-to-collect-more-information/td-p/613718), [questions regarding the same "issue"](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Add-custom-input-fields-to-cart/td-p/154710) or other resources in general.

---

I suggest for **further reading** purposes to check out some of these links and guides (*some may be mentioned above*):

- https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/cart-notes
- https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/checkout-form (! very good in-depth example)
- https://www.christhefreelancer.com/shopify-liquid-guide/
- https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/theme-templates/cart-liquid
- https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference
- https://www.shopify.com/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet (! helpful cheatsheet)
- https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Cart-Use-cart-attributes-to-collect-more-information/td-p/613718
- https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Add-custom-input-fields-to-cart/td-p/154710
- https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Get-customization-information-for-products/td-p/616503

Comment: RE: Shopify's Liquid Documentation. That blog post you mentioned does a great job describing the language but it does not really talk about fetching data from the "outer space". I frankly do not think there are any "best practices" in regards to that. I've seen a few projects that simply use jQuery.ajax()..

Comment: @mikek Yeah - I saw those (= GitHub repos using jQuery for example) when doing my research as well. The reason I linked the Shopify's Liquid Documentation is simply for the sake of completeness. You never know - maybe someone will read this in a few months and might be glad to have this source. Anyhow, the latter about `cart notes` specifically is **extremely** useful in regards to your question (as I linked).

Comment: @J.M.Arnold The post you shared about storing user data is exactly what I'm trying to figure out.  I need to store a 3rd party API access token for a store.  Do you know if Metafields are now an appropriate place to keep them?

If not, I'm not sure if there's a secure way to match the Shopify store owner up to one of our users and their access token.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial specifically for creating custom shopify input field for getting engraving information: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Get-customization-information-for-products/td-p/616503